# Show that $f(t, B_t)$ is only a function about $t$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion. For a two-variable smooth function $f(t, x)$ with second order differentiable continuous (i.e., $f\in C^{1,2}$), if $f(t, B_t)$ is a finite variation process, show that $f$ is only a function about $t$.

---

My work:

I only try the Ito formula
$$
df(t, B_t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t}dB_t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial B_t^2}dt
$$

Comment: Why the close vote ???

Comment: the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t}$ has to be null, so $f$ is not depending on $B$ otherwise the non finite variation term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t}dB_t$ is alive. (The term $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial B_t^2}$ is also null as the first partial is null). In the end only the term depending  on $t$ is still there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(t,B_t)$ is a finite variation process,its quadratic variation

$$
\left[f(s,B_s)\right]_t=\int_0^t \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(s,B_s)\right)^2 ds=0,\forall t >0
$$.This means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$.Hence $f $ is only a function about $t$.

Comment: Why is the quadratic variation zero?

Comment: @Hermi,this is a elementary property about F.V. and Q.V. .See https://formulasearchengine.com/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Finite_variation_processes